# SQL between dates including start and end dates

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this:

```
 (CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
```

Works fine.

But when the `CURDATE()` is 2011-12-02 and the `end_date` is 2011-12-02 will it grab the row?

E.g my start_date is 2011-12-01 00:00:00 and my end date is 2011-12-02 23:59:59

So it only works when the date is between but not if it's ON the `end_date` itself.

Or maybe it should check for the time too, because it still needs to be selected with this query when it's 2011-12-02 15:30:00 for example.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well the obvious answer is to subtract 1 day from `start_date`, and add 1 day to `end_date`, but I'm not posting this as an answer because there may be a better SQL alternative.

Comment: @dave, someone else did!

Comment: between means excluding start and end so the result is correct. So it only works when the date is between but not if it's ON the end_date itself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, you could try

```
CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 6):

Since both columns are timestamps, you need to make sure times don't trip you up. 
To keep the times from tripping you up, cast the timestamps to date.

```
where current_date between cast(start_date as date) 
                       and cast(end_date as date);
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the answer to this question refers to a bug in an old version of MySql because `between` **is inclusive**, which means it will grab rows between the start and end dates inclusive, not just between the start and one day before the end.

Try this:

```
SELECT CURDATE() BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE();
```

The result is `1` (i.e. `true`).
I believe the original poster problem lies with mixing up proper dates (`DATE`) and dates with time (`DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`).

Try this:

```
SELECT NOW() BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE();
SELECT NOW() BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

The result is `0` for the first select and `1` for the second. What happened is a `DATE` is equivalent to a `DATETIME` with zero time so unless `NOW()` is called exactly at midnight it will be greater than `CURDATE()` and fall outside of the `BETWEEN` statement.
To prevent this test only the `DATE` part of a `DATETIME` using the `DATE()` function:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `start_date <= CURDATE() AND end_date > CURDATE()`

Answer (score 1):

It will work ... `BETWEEN` works inclusive of the boundary values. That is,

```
(CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
```

including start_date,end_date and any day falling between

```
CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: But if start_date has a time that's after midnight . . .

Answer (score 0):

cast (end_date - Start_date as double precision) * 86400