# Having a startDate and endDate, fetch all active results for today from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with the field `startDate` and `endDate` (each being datatype `DATE`), so let's say the values for a record could be `2015-08-09` and `2015-08-12`.

Today is `2015-08-10`, how do I fetch all active records from the database?

Active is everything where today is between startDate and endDate. (including, if today equals `startDate` and/or `endDate`)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354638/sql-between-dates-including-start-and-end-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE startdate <= CURDATE() AND endDate => CURDATE()
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table 
where CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND endDate
```